# Framelayout doesn't persist in recyclerview cell

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my `layout`, I have a `recyclerview` containing cells that are `cardviews` that, in theory, contains a `framelayout`. Ideally, the `framelayout` within the `cardview` can be populated with a `fragment` that is dependent on `Object` used to populate the `view`. However, when I have multiple cells, only one cell contains the `framelayout`. This phenomenon shows on the screen as so:

the code used to intialize the viewholder for the recyclerview cell is shown below:

```
public class JokesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView userName;
    TextView likeCounterTextView;
    TextView commentCounterTextView;
    TextView timeStampTextView;
    CircleImageView profileImg;
    ImageButton likeButton;
    ImageButton options;
    ImageButton comments;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;


    public JokesViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        timeStampTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.time_date_textView);
        frameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.post_content);
        profileImg = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_imageview);
        userName = view.findViewById(R.id.username_textView);

        options = view.findViewById(R.id.options_imageButton);
        options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //todo open custom dialog
            }
        });

        likeButton = view.findViewById(R.id.favorite_imageButton);
        likeCounterTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.likes_counter_textView);

        comments = view.findViewById(R.id.comment_imageButton);
        commentCounterTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.comment_counter_textView);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        view.setTag(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //todo open fragment to show all post data plus comments
    }
}

 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final JokesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Joke joke = jokes.get(position);
    holder.userName.setText(joke.getUser());

    Constants.DATABASE.child("users/" + joke.getUID() + "/urlString")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String url = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    Glide.with(context).load(url).into(holder.profileImg);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
    Constants.DATABASE.child("userpostslikescomments/" + joke.getUID() + "/" + joke.getPushId() + "/likes/num")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Integer num = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                    holder.likeCounterTextView.setText(Integer.toString(0));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
    Constants.DATABASE.child("userpostslikescomments/" + joke.getUID() + "/" + joke.getPushId() + "/comments/num")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Integer num = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                    holder.commentCounterTextView.setText(Integer.toString(0));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
    Constants.DATABASE.child("userpostslikescomments/" + joke.getUID() + "/" + joke.getPushId() + "/likes/list/" + Constants.UID)
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        holder.likeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
                    } else {
                        holder.likeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            });

    if (joke.getMediaURL().equals("")) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("jokeTitle", joke.getJokeTitle());
        bundle.putString("jokeBody", joke.getJokeBody());
        bundle.putString("tagline", joke.getTagline());
        //may not work
        TextPostContent tpc = new TextPostContent();
        tpc.setArguments(bundle);
        ((android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction().add(holder.frameLayout.getId(), tpc).commit();
    } else if (joke.getMediaURL().contains(".png")) {//may need to take into account more file types
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("media_url", joke.getMediaURL());
        bundle.putString("tagline", joke.getTagline());
        ImagePostContent ipc = new ImagePostContent();
        ipc.setArguments(bundle);
        ((android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction().add(holder.frameLayout.getId(), ipc).commit();
    } else {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("media_url", joke.getMediaURL());
        bundle.putString("tagline", joke.getTagline());
        VideoPostContent vpc = new VideoPostContent();
        vpc.setArguments(bundle);
        ((android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction().add(holder.frameLayout.getId(), vpc).commit();
    }

    holder.timeStampTextView.setText(joke.getTimeStamp());

    holder.likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String path = "userpostslikescomments/" + joke.getUID() + "/" + joke.getPushId() + "/likes/list/" + Constants.UID;
            Constants.DATABASE.child(path)
                    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                Constants.DATABASE.child(path).removeValue();
                                holder.likeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp);
                            } else {
                                Constants.DATABASE.child(path).setValue(true);
                                holder.likeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                    });
        }
    });

    holder.comments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //todo start animation between fragments
            //todo show recyclerview of comments
        }
    });
}
```

My gut tells me that instead of doing a fragment transaction I should add views (like `textviews` and `imageviews`) programmtically. But I was wondering if there was a way to populate the `framelayout` of the `cardviews` using the `fragment` classes I already created?

Comment: Hmm. Two questions: 1. do all the ViewHolders use the same layout in `onCreateViewHolder`? 2. are the FrameLayouts missing in the layout inspector too?

Comment: All viewholders use the same layout. Using the layout inspector, when there are two recyclerview cells present, both framelayouts are seen, but only one is populated (with the information that should be split between the two cells)

Comment: Ok, new day, new eyes....if you turn on FragmentManager debugging with `getSupportFragmentManager().enableDebugLogging(true)`, do you see the right number of add events? If so, I think it might be that all the `holder.frameLayout`s have the same layout id, so it's effectively searching for view by id in the activity each time and grabbing the same target `FrameLayout`. You could assign unique ids in onBindViewHolder - something based on index, maybe?

Comment: Thx for the help, it was exactly the case. In order to solve the problem I found the framelayout reference by searching for the original id then I set the id to something different by calling frameLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to ensure that each cell within the recyclerview has a framelayout that is populated with either text, an image, or a video (versus having only one cell having a framelayout populated with information that should be split into multiple cells) you should call `frameLayout.setId(View.generateViewId())` after finding a reference to the framelayout via `findViewById(int)`. Fast scrolling leads to a fatal error though. Another solution is to create mulitple view holders for the different types of cells.